# Compute Lateral and Angular Error for path following

Tags: python, ros, robotics

I'm working on a project related to path following in ROS. I have a Roomba robot which have to follow a path.

To code the path follower AI, I need to compute both Lateral and Angular error.

I have 3 information of my robot (x, y, and yaw) and coord (x, y) of a point path.

**To compute the lateral error I use this formula:**

```
dx = path_x - robot_x 
dy = path_y - robot_y

path_yaw = math.atan2(dy, dx) 

cos_yaw = math.cos(yaw)
sin_yaw = math.sin(yaw)

error_lat_ = dx * s_yaw - dy * c_yaw
```

This formula gives me wrong results. Let's see if we set robot_x and robot_y to 0.

For above point (x, y) results are:

**Good:**

- (1, 0) = 0
- (-1, 0) = 3.14

**Wrong**

- (0, 1) = 0
- (0, -1) = 0

For (0, 1) and (0, -1), the lateral should be 1.

**To compute the Angular error I use this formula:**

```
error_ang_ = norm_angle(robot_yaw - path_yaw)
```

norme_angle: normalize to stay between Pi and -Pi

For above point(x, y) results are:

**Good**

- (1, 0) = 0
- (-1, 0) = 3.14

**Wrong**

- (0, 1) = 1.57
- (0, -1) = -1.57

Correct results for (0, 1) should be -1.57 sign is not good.

Do you know if these formulas are not correct or if I'm doing something wrong.

NB: Result is wrong when y is not 0.